# Get HRIS hours worked data to calculate hours worked - hours on lunch, to get a total of hours worked in a day, in Power Bi

Tags: sorting, filter, powerbi

I am trying to get my power bi data from my HRIS platform to calculate hours worked - hours on lunch, to get a total of hours worked in a day.

I have tried grouping, pivots, formulas, and because my HRIS platform send the "check-in" time at the start of a shift and the "check-in" time when they clock back in from lunch, as the same "check-in" classification, I cannot associate it with one or the other, it picks the most recent one, if I say return "check-in" (My data set is intraday and updates every hour so I can get all Clock events for the current day)

I have included an example of what my data looks like right from the HRIS into Power Bi

[Sample Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31e6S.png)

[Full Data Sheet Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cADbY.png)

Formula's Used in Order:

```
Check In = 
 IF(AND(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
 Week],Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]="Check-in"),
 Merge1[Clock_Event_Time_-_No_Time_Zone])



 Check Out (Lunch) = 
IF(Merge1[Day of the Week]= Merge1[Current Day],
IF(Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]= "Check-out 
(meal)",Merge1[Clock_Event_Time_-_No_Time_Zone],BLANK()))


Check in (Lunch) = IF(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],
VAR checkin = Merge1[Check In]
VAR outlunch = Merge1[Check Out (Lunch)]
VAR timeinfromlunch = IF(checkin>outlunch,checkin)
return timeinfromlunch)


Check Out = IF(Merge1[Day of the Week]= Merge1[Current Day],
IF(Merge1[Clock_Event_Type] = "Check-out", 
Merge1[Clock_Event_Time_-_No_Time_Zone]),BLANK())


Current Time = IF(AND(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]="Check-in"),
NOW()
)



CPH Calc (Intraday Shift) = IF(Merge1[Current Time]<Merge1[Shift 
End Today],Merge1[Current Time],Merge1[Check Out])


Hours Worked = 
IF(AND(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]="Check-in"),
VAR totalsecondsinbreak = DATEDIFF(Merge1[Check Out 
(Lunch)],Merge1[Check in (Lunch)],SECOND)

VAR total_secondsworking = DATEDIFF(Merge1[Check In],Merge1[CPH 
Calc (Intraday Shift)],SECOND)
VAR totalseconds = total_secondsworking-totalsecondsinbreak

VAR DAXHours =  (totalseconds/60)/60

RETURN IF(Merge1[Clock_Event_Time_- 
_No_Time_Zone]=0,BLANK(),DAXHours))


Shift Start Today = IF(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],TODAY() + Merge1[Start Shift])

Shift End Today = IF(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],TODAY() + Merge1[End Shift])

On Queue (Milliseconds) = IF(AND(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day 
of the Week],Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]="Check-in"),
VAR onqueueseconds = RELATED('Table (2)'[On Queue])
VAR milliseconds = onqueueseconds
VAR total_second = milliseconds/1000
VAR minutes = total_second/60 
VAR hours_decimal = minutes/60 
VAR hours = INT(hours_decimal) 
return onqueueseconds)


Utilization = 
IF(AND(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]="Check-in"),
VAR productivetime = Merge1[Hours Productive Time]
VAR workedtime = Merge1[Hours Worked]
VAR Ult = IFERROR(productivetime/workedtime,BLANK())
return Ult
)


Hours Productive Time = 
IF(AND(Merge1[Current Day]=Merge1[Day of the 
Week],Merge1[Clock_Event_Type]="Check-in"),
VAR milliseconds = Merge1[On Queue (Milliseconds)]
VAR total_second = milliseconds/1000
//VAR minutes = total_second/60 
//VAR hours_decimal = minutes/60 
//VAR hours = INT(hours_decimal)
VAR DAXHours =  (total_second/60)/60 
return DAXHours+.5)
```

Comment: I think this question is too broadly written to get a good answer. Could you try expanding it by showing your best attempt (i.e. include the formula and results you tried, describe what's wrong with the specific results you show, and describe the results you were expecting to get instead)

Comment: Yes Thank you for replying let me add that to this right now

Comment: @AaronBrager Here is sample data with everything in my actual data, and a screenshot of the sheet.

There are 4 clock events in a day, but 3 codes, I cannot change what the HRIS system gives me, so trying to calculate how to differentiate the check-in (start shift) and the check-in (back from lunch) also they are on different rows so sum them has proven difficult to get a total hours worked.